Can we recover a database from a deleted server in Azure SQL
We are testing our disaster recovery routines.
If we delete a database it is possible to get it back. Is it also possible if we delete a server? There is this 8 year old answer, is this still the correct answer, or are there new options? Can we for example use Recovery Vault?
Can we recover a deleted server for Azure SQL Database?

when is your database got deleted How many days ago?

We are just testing, I deleted a test server an hour ago.

A server and a database are not the same thing, @ShirazBhaiji . Have you DROPed a database, or removed a server?


Can we recover a database from a deleted server in Azure SQL.

If you deleted the Azure SQL server, you cannot recover it by your own. In this situation you should call Azure Support within 7 days, they can help you restore the Azure SQL server including databases and backups.
Under below condition Azure SQL Server can be recovered:

Recovery conditions for a Azure SQ Server

A new Azure SQL Server with the same name has not been re-created since deletion.
The Azure SQL Server was deleted within the last 7 days, including today. Otherwise, it cannot be recovered.


You need to provide belwo details to support team:

Server name
Region name
Subscription owner approval .

You need to create a support Request as below from here:

